# Extract coefficients' p-value from fit.mult.impute

Tags: r, hmisc

I've used multiple imputation in R to deal with missing values using the `aregImpute` function from the `Hmisc` library. For analysis, I use the `fit.mult.impute` function to correct the variance for the multiple imputation process.

I want to create a table with coefficients and p-values. Coefficients can be extracted from `fit.mult.impute` using the `$coef` suffix, but I can't manage to extract the p-value. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, p-value columns are stored as p.value, so you could get it by `data$p.value`, but you can see it with `head(data)`, the column names and what kind of data you have there.

Answer (score 0):

If the object created by `fit.mult.impute` is called `fit`, you can use

```
coef(summary(fit))[, 4]
```

to extract all p-values.